# Как сделать include в WP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Я хочу в шоткод добавить include файла html

Файл функции будет в папке с плагинами, и вот хочу что бы мнного было шоткодов и подключать к ним html файлы. Это возможно?

```
function om_le() {
return '
include ('plagin/test/num1.html'); 
';
}
add_shortcode('om', 'o_le');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде три ошибки: имя функции не соответствует шорткоду, вы возвращаете просто строку, в которой что-то там написано, и у вас одинарные кавычки внутри таких же. Чтобы вернуть вывод на экран include как строку, надо использовать функции буферизации php:

```
function om_le() {
    ob_start();
    include 'plagin/test/num1.html';
    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'om', 'om_le' );
```

Comment: Разобрался, и подключил через 
`return_once('link.html');`